# python reverse tokens in a string

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
apple.orange.red.green.yellow
```

How can i reverse it to get the following:

```
yellow.green.red.orange.apple
```

Comment: You're starting to sound like you have a much larger question that you ought to get around to asking...

Answer (score 7):

I like this (more readable?) one:

```
>> s = "yellow.green.red.orange.apple"
>> '.'.join(reversed(s.split('.')))
'apple.orange.red.green.yellow'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
'.'.join(s.split('.')[::-1])
```